# how to convert keycode to character in "angularjs" Using Expressoins

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui, razorengine

Razor Code:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
         {
          <br /><div class="rowId">@((char)(@i + 65))</div>
        }
```

It is working well with the above Visual Studio Razor syntax.

But I need to do it with angularjs. I am Very new to angularjs so help to solve this issue..

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Use

String.fromCharCode(yourvalue);

I created plunker see there :-)
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/wMGPKPLG1hpMboS0Y9GB?p=preview